# How to replace tinkerpop imports by janus-graph imports during initialization of gremlin groovy script engine?

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, javascript-engine, groovyscriptengine

I initialize gremlin-script-engine with janus-plugin in this way:

```
GremlinScriptEngineManager engineManager = new DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager();
engineManager.addPlugin(JanusGraphGremlinPlugin.instance());
engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("gremlin-groovy");
```

Engine normally evaluates queries with some janus elements (e.g. `Multiplicity.ONE2MANY`):

```
qu = "mgmt.makeEdgeLabel('"+ TEST_EDGE_LABEL+"').multiplicity(ONE2MANY).make();";
engine.evalWithManagementTransaction(qu);
```

... but for the query:

```
qu = "mgmt.makePropertyKey('"+TEST_PROPERTY_KEY+"')"
        + ".dataType(String.class).cardinality(Cardinality.SINGLE).make();";
```

I get:

```
MissingPropertyException: No such property: SINGLE for class: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.VertexProperty$Cardinality
```

It seems that the script-engine tries to use  `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.VertexProperty$Cardinality` and not janus one `org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality`.

PS: If I use full name of class `org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE` or only value of `Cardinality` enum (e.g. just `SINGLE`) in query then all works fine.

How could I remove tinkerpop imports or force script-engine to use janus imports from plugin... or it makes sense to change gremlin-queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the console you can do and alias:

```
gremlin> import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.VertexProperty.Cardinality as Card
gremlin> Card
==>class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.VertexProperty$Cardinality
```

But I don't think that will work for the Gremlin ScriptEngine for some reason. I don't think we've exposed the ability to alias there.

I think you would have to use the full class name of `org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.SINGLE`. Of course, I would wonder why you would be doing schema modifications this way. Typically, schema modifications are administrative functions that you would handle outside of the `GremlinScriptEngine` and more directly in your code or in the console as a script.